# Accuracy of the Inflation theory

Tags: big-bang-theory, cosmological-inflation

In the Inflation theory, it said that the Inflationary epoch has happened $10^{-32} \,\mathrm{s}$ after the Big Bang, and I cannot find anything related to how this number was calculated and how accurate was it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the original paper?  By Alan Guth I think.  it may be explained there. The paper is here.  https://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.23.347

Comment: Un sourced vegue understanding, hence comment not answer: at the end of inflation, the decay of the inflaton field produced a lot of other particle and radiation which filled space. The density and termperature of these can be estimated from basic physics. Tracking backwards we can estimate when the universe was that hot and dense.

Comment: @jmh Thank you. That was helpful.